Dedicated ground vs power cord ground?
So my Siglent 1104X-E oscilloscope has no dedicated ground- it uses the power cord's ground.
My Siglent function generator has a dedicated ground (screw terminal with banana plug option). Obviously I know that a dedicated ground is better because it nullifies any interference that may be on the mains. (Or prevents interference from entering the mains in the case of my TIG welder, whose instructions specify a dedicated copper ground rod seperate from the one connected to the service.)

Why is it that the oscilloscope doesn't need one while the generator does?

Also, do most of you have your equipment with dedicated grounds attached to a copper ground rod hammered into the earth? (And if not- and assuming you connect the dedicated ground to the mains, how is that any different than just using the power cord?)


Thank you

Which model signal genetator it is?

@Justme SDG1032X

That ground terminal on a power supply or function generator or other piece of equipment is typically intended to give you a way to connect other things to mains ground, not as a way to ground the equipment. It's directly connected to mains earth, and can be used to ground-reference the output of a floating-output device.

Thank you for the explanation. So the mains ground is sufficient for most things? No need to worry about interference and the dedicated rod unless you have something putting off very high current HF radiation?

@Rahman Yes, mains ground is good enough for almost all uses. It's sufficient for the high-power RF that goes on in the lab I work at, though an arc welder might create issues. Remember to use the ground spring on your scope probe if you're getting interference; the long wire on the ground clip can pick up radiated noise very easily, even if there's no noise on the signal or the ground it's attached to.

Hearth is correct.
I too have an amateur Electronics lab.  The AC powered test equipment that is grounded (3-wire) that include your oscilloscope, is connected to mains ground. (Also have that same model and LOVE! it)
This is why if you are testing any other AC powered devices you want ...geez, what to you call it? a ground isolation? isolator?
Regarding your TIG welder. I would guess that is a high amp draw unit. Just do connect your scope probes or any metal part of the oscilloscope or related test equipment to the TIG. I would suggest to even run the welder on a separate Household/shop AC circuit.
Maybe you are questioning the TIG ground cable connection that does straight to your house ground wire, or maybe you yourself have connected the TIG ground cable directly to a six foot deep rod in the ground. (this sounds odd to me, but whatever..I can be an idiot at times.
So, that grounding rod is connected to your mains electrical panel, the ground in your mains electrical panel is connected directly the the ground socket in all of your outlets that have a 3rd prong. Thus your scope is already directly connected to earth ground.
I know this is really a verbose answer, I hope it covers any others aspects of your question that there may be

Yeah the TIG has an HF inverter that can cause really bad interference despite it being mains grounded. Fluorescent lights flickering off every time I start the arc, interference on TVs, audio equipment, etc. The manual specifically states "The HF service bolt should be connected directly to a 12 gauge wire that is bonded directly to an outside copper ground rod driven into moist soil...

...Additionally, all metal items including any metal frame or sheeting of the building should be connected and grounded to separate copper
ground rods driven into the ground at 10 foot intervals around the perimeter of the building. This includes items such as tables, carts, rack material,
metal surrounds, etc. that may act as “antenna” to radiate/absorb HF energy."

And yeah its a 240V so it gets a dedicated 30A breaker; but that doesn't help with the interference. (Well maybe it does- I have never tried connecting any sensitive electronics to that circuit)
